# Selenium clicking <a> element with By.LinkText, how to ignore \r\n inside link text

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

I have an a element with text including \r\n inside it's text. HTML is as follows:

```
<a href="/Profile/ProfileView?isSuccessScreen=1&amp;URLID=x/ayvqzf7zojzzqiauihka" class="list green profile  ">
  <img src="/content/css/theme/images/profile.svg" />
  <span>Complete your</span>
  <h2>Profile</h2>
</a>
```

I would like to use `Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Complete your Profile"));` to find it and then click on it but it is failing because the link text has \r\n formatting inside span tag. Is there any way to ignore the \r\n inside the link text? Please don't suggest partial link text and respond if it's possible to ignore \r\n formatting or any other way to achieve it using the link text function. Thanks. Element details are as follows:

```
{Element (id = 0.9715823630081235-1)}
    Coordinates: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteCoordinates}
    Displayed: true
    Enabled: true
    Id: "0.9715823630081235-1"
    Location: {X = 848 Y = 339}
    LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView: {X = 848 Y = 339}
    Selected: false
    Size: {Width = 465 Height = 80}
    TagName: "a"
    Text: "Complete your\r\nProfile"
    WrappedDriver: {OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver}
```

Comment: Did you try to simply copy/paste link text from rendered webpage? Not from dev-console, but from the page viewport. Or try `"Complete your\nProfile"`

Comment: can't copy from the browser viewport but "Complete your\nProfile" worked. Thanks  
 :)

Comment: @Andersson Post your comment as an answer so OP can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the text from **a** tag, you can extract the text as string and replace the **\r\n** symbols  it or use an xpath:

> //a[normalize-space(text()='Complete your profile')]